# Scanner not reading the next line over and exiting loop

Tags: java, loops, java.util.scanner

Hi i am doing a program which allows a user to insert paragraphs of data into a scanner input and i have a loop to check the next line if its blank to break but i want it to check the next 2-3 lines for text because it auto exits when paragraphs

The code:

```
    String tex ="";
    String line;
    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        line = in.nextLine();
        if (line.isEmpty()) {
            break;
        }
        tex += line + "\n";
    }
```

Would i just add another if statement? or is there a more efficient way to get the desired output i am looking for?. i want to be able to post a paragraph or two into the scanner (im using a scanner for a bigger purpose) without it pre-terminating.

Comment: What's the bigger purpose?

Comment: Try using `continue` instead of `break`.

Comment: @VictorPoloDeGyvesMontero im doing a substitution cipher program and one of the ways i want to input text is by allowing paragraphs of words to be copied and pasted (scanner) into a text string that  is i manipulate later to encrypt/decrypt/letter frequency

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution to your problem.

Count the number of times that the condition `isBlank()` is `TRUE` consecutively
and `BREAK` if maximum accepted.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final var MAXIMUM_LINE_TESTED = 2;
    var counterTest = 0;

    try (var sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

        final var al = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("Enter text:");
        while (true) {
            final var line = sc.nextLine();
            if (line.isBlank()) {
                counterTest++;
                if (counterTest >= MAXIMUM_LINE_TESTED)
                    break;
            } else {
                counterTest = 0;
            }
            al.add(line);
        }

        for (final String v : al) {
            System.out.println(v);
        }

    }
}
```

### Before update 26.02.21 :

> The continue statement breaks one iteration (in the loop), if a specified condition occurs, and continues with the next iteration in the loop.

> The break statement can also be used to jump out of a loop.

[by w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_break.asp)

---

You must use `CONTINUE` so as not to exit the `WHILE`. `BREAK` stops the `WHILE` if the condition is `true`.

### `CONTINUE`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n" 
            + " \n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n";
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s)) {
        String line = "", text = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.isBlank()) {
                System.out.println("skipped");
                continue;
            }
            text += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

### `BREAK`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n" 
            + " \n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n"
            + "hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!hello world!\n";
    try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(s)) {
        String line = "", text = "";
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            line = scanner.nextLine();
            if (line.isBlank()) {
                System.out.println("skipped");
                break;
            }
            text += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesnt the first example one infinitely continue and the second one just infinitely put skipped? i need it to allow paragraphs but i also need it to stop at the end as well.

Comment: if using an input of text typed it the false wouldnt occur considering it uses the if line.isblank it just adds skips and goes to the next line over and over again

Comment: True, Count the number of times that the condition isBlank() is TRUE consecutively and BREAK if maximum accepted. I add an example to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

After several hours searching for solutions, this is how i was able to resolve the issue.
To prevent scanner.nextLine(); from exiting while loop, You need to duplicate it. Add another Scanner.nextLine(); to the end of the while loop.

```
String tex ="";
String line;
while (true) {
    line = in.nextLine();
    if (line.isEmpty()) {
        break;
    }
    tex += line + "\n";
    in.nextLine()
}
```